# Setting Maxmemory and Maxmemory-Policy in Kubernetes using kubectl apply yaml

Tags: kubernetes, redis

Is there a way to set maxmemory and maxmemory-policy for Redis on Kubernetes?

I am using the command kubectl apply -f redis-cache.yaml

The file redis-cache.yaml contains this content:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
data:
  redis-config: |
    maxmemory 256
    maxmemory-policy allkeys-lru
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: redis-cache
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: redis-cache
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: redis-cache
    spec:
      nodeSelector:
        "beta.kubernetes.io/os": linux
      containers:
      - name: redis-cache
        image: redis
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 128Mi
          limits:
            cpu: 150m
            memory: 256Mi
        ports:
        - containerPort: 6379
          name: redis
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: redis-cache
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 6379
  selector:
    app: redis-cache
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Kubernetes `deployment` doesn't have field named `data`.

You can provide the configuration via `ConfigMap` or `Secret`. The Redis configuration file is located at `installdir/redis/etc/redis.conf`.

**ConfigMap:**

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: redis-config
data:
  redis.conf: |-
    maxmemory 256
    maxmemory-policy allkeys-lru
```

**Deployment:**

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: redis-cache
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: redis-cache
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: redis-cache
    spec:
      nodeSelector:
        "beta.kubernetes.io/os": linux
      volumes:
      - name: redis-config
        configMap:
          name: redis-config
      containers:
      - name: redis-cache
        image: redis
        volumeMounts:
        - name: redis-config
          mountPath: /redis/etc
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 128Mi
          limits:
            cpu: 150m
            memory: 256Mi
        ports:
        - containerPort: 6379
          name: redis
```

Comment: Works perfectly.  I needed to adapt it a bit using this guide https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/configuration/configure-redis-using-configmap/